# How to execute a script before database schema generation in Grails?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using Grails 2.5.5. In my bootstrap I registered a static method for String to generate UUIDs:

```
String.metaClass.static.uuid = { ->
  java.util.UUID.randomUUID().toString()
}
```

And on my domain classes, I want to use that method to initialize a uid field:

```
class Organization {

   String uid = String.uuid()
   ...
}
```

The problem is when I run my Grails app, it generates the database schema, and that seems to happen before executing the Bootstrap. The generation creates instances of the domain classes, but the String.uuid() is not yet registered so I get a MissingMethodException.

How can I create a script that runs before the database schema generation to register all my methods there so they are available at schema generation time?

FYI: full stacktrace

```
2016-11-08 17:11:23,638 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error creating b
ean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreatio
nException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'se
ssionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invoc
ation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hib
ernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.
beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while
setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with nam
e 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.codeh
aus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister
    Line | Method
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while sett
ing bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 's
essionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.codehaus.
groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersister
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibern
ate.MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityPersist
er
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MappingException: Could not get constructor for org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate.persister.entity.GroovyAwareSingleTableEntityP
ersister
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InstantiationException: could not instantiate test object : com.cabolabs.ehrserver.query.Query
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by InvocationTargetException: null
->>  262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static java.lang.String.uuid() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: wait(), trim(), dump(), find(), wait(long), is(java.lang.Object)
->>   28 | <init>    in com.cabolabs.ehrserver.query.Query
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    262 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    744 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend you create a plugin for your feature so you can use the `loadBefore` capabilities of a plugin to ensure that your feature is added before other plugins. The Grails documentation on plugins describes how to [Control Load Order](http://docs.grails.org/2.4.x/guide/plugins.html#understandingPluginLoadOrder) in some detail.

Comment: In my case that would be something like loadBefore  = [ 'domain'] ? The docs don't seem to display all the possible values for the loadBefore.

Comment: Actually, I think you want `loadBefore = ['database-migration']` so your plugin loads before the database migration plugin. I'm not 100% sure on the plugin name, but a quick glance at the source makes me think the above would be correct.